# Erase a folder and it's files completely from a speceific dirctory using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently writing a little program to "reset" hard drives. In this program the user should be able to choose if he wants to have everything deleted completely or just a part of it, e.g a special folder.
Since I want to provide anonymousity to all pre-owners, I want to completely delete the folder or the drive, essentially I want to format a single folder.

The problem is, that with file recovery tools it is very easy to restore deleted files, since they are mostly not erased but just thrown out of the file system. How can I set all bytes that were taken by the folder and the files in it to Zero, or at least make them inrepairable?

I'm using python 2.7 and Debian

Comment: One interesting problem you might run into is if the person is on an SSD then it can be really hard if not impossible to completely change all of the data for the folder to 0s. An SSD has a controller built into its hardware that will distribute writes onto different sectors of the drive to reduce premature sector failure. So if you think you are writing 0s to one sector the drive has really directed you to another sector and you can't tell from the OS.

Comment: [Here is an article by Kingston on the issue](https://www.kingston.com/us/community/articledetail/articleid/29539)

Comment: Actually the same can be said for a lot of modern spinning disk hard drives. They also have controllers that will change the sector you are writing to without your knowledge to avoid bad sectors or reduce wear and tear.

Comment: I jsut read the article, and I really appreciated that tip. :)  I willl keep that in mind, but I still can't do it on a "normal" drive al well... :/

Comment: Whoops! I read your comment too late....

Comment: [Here is a reddit thread that might help.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/26eu73/script_to_parse_hard_drive/) Wiping a file path is not as easy as it might first appear. With each file system the way you would wipe the data is different, for each OS it changes, and for each drive it can also be a little different. A good place to start would be figuring out if there are any python libraries for each major file system and reading the docs.

Comment: I really hope you continue this project. When you are done you should make a library that will delete data from a drive independent of file system or any other variable and put it on github. It will be a god send for anyone else trying to do this in the future. I am sorry I can't be of more help :(

Comment: FWIW, there's a standard *nix command for this: `shred`. It's great for shredding whole drives or partitions, but it's not so good for getting rid of single files or folders on modern filesystems, for the reason mentioned above. You _could_ write a large file to the partition so it has almost no free space, do the shredding operation, and remove the large file. But doing that regularly on a SSD or other flash drive is not a great idea due to the increased write wear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly a solution! Perfect!

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-de/shred.1.de.html

You can shred files and directorys and whole partitions with it and it is for DEBIAN!!! You can set all bytes to zero if you want and many more options! Great command for such jobs!

Comment: Beware the man page says explicitely: *CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place. This is the traditional way to do things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this assumption.*

Comment: I saw that! I just tried it with some files on a USB-stick and at least on this one, it worked!